# Origin of "slow on the uptake"

Tags: etymology, metaphors

Does anyone know what the literal reference to "slow on the uptake" is and where it originated?  I have only ever found similar phrases, but this one.  I know its meaning.

Answer (score 4):

***[Uptake](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=uptake)***  (n.) meaning ability to understand is from the beginning of the 19th century. There might be an analogy with the later meaning that refers to a "pipe leading up from the smoke box":

> - ***"capacity for understanding, perceptive power," 1816, from up (adv.) + take (v.).*** Compare Middle English verb uptake "to pick or take up" (c. 1300).
> - Meaning "pipe leading up from the smoke box of a steam boiler to the chimney" is from 1839.

According to ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slow%20on%20the%20uptake%2Cquick%20on%20the%20uptake&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslow%20on%20the%20uptake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquick%20on%20the%20uptake%3B%2Cc0)*** the expressions "[slow/quick on the uptake](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slow+on+the+uptake)" are both from the early 20th century.

Comment: This covers some ground but doesn't quite answer why it's "on the uptake". Normally you would say "I'm slow at learning" or "I'm slow to learn" or "My learning is slow", not "I'm slow on the learn". There are parallels like "quick on the draw".